# Bluehost keeps a copy of forwarded emails

Tags: email, bluehost

I've set up email forwarding successfully on Bluehost, but it appears they keep a copy of forwarded email. I was able to log in to webmail ("roundcube") and see all of them.

Is there any way to disable the 2nd part, so the emails are just cleanly forwarded (bounced?) over and Bluehost does not keep a copy?

Comment: Is your hosting account using cPanel? If so, you'll need to delete the account and just leave the forwarding so the box is removed -  or alternatively create a filter to delete all new mail. The filter setup is a bit tricky so that it will still forward prior to deleting, so see the bottom of [this](https://features.cpanel.net/topic/forwarder-keeps-a-copy-on-the-server-then-its-not-a-forwarder) thread for more info on how to set that up.

Comment: Does Bluehost not have tech support or a forum at all?

Comment: Does Bluehost have extremely bad support or something? We seem to have a lot of users asking questions when using BlueHost lately. As a paying customer, they should be your first point of contact. Not saying the question is not welcome through.

Comment: @dan that was it, thanks! Good call. I deleted the "email account" and left the "forwarder". Seems obvious in retrospect.

Comment: No problem, good luck!

Comment: @Rob and simon-hayter , I couldn't find a bluhost email support option or forum where I could post questions, and I found a Bluehost tag here on webmasters.stackexchange.com so I proceeded with my question.

Comment: @dan will you make that an answer (below)? I'll accept it to help others out in the future!

Comment: Thanks, aside from the occasional comment, I stopped answering questions years ago to focus on moderating and give others a chance to. Feel free to provide an answer and accept it when you can, you'll earn some more reputation here (sorry someone downvoted this btw).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that as well as a forwarder, you have a mailbox.

A mailbox isn't necessary to have a forwarder work.  However having one will do what you describe, forward the emails plus keep a copy.

Comment: This was it, thank you. And I forgot that I was using that email account for _outgoing_ mail, so I still need it.

Comment: @Adam If you are using gmail, make a new account something like _outgoing@example.com_ and use that.  It won't collect any emails (unless you give it out to anyone) but gmail can still send as your domain email address.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not following, Steve. Is this something I can do at Bluehost? Can you be more specific?

Comment: @AdamMonsen Firstly at Bluehost you have your forwarder (e.g. info@) redirecting to gmail.  Next at Bluehost you make a mailbox (e.g. outgoing@) and note the password.  Now go to gmail and in settings > accounts and import > send mail as and create the info@ email address.  When it asks you for SMTP details use your own mail server and login using outgoing@ - so it sends through your server via outgoing@ but the from email will be info@